# At the same controller, GET and POST works, but PUT don't

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a Web Api 2 service with latest .NET Framework and C#.

I have a controller with these methods:

```
public IEnumerable<User> Get()
{
    // ...
}

public User Get(int id)
{
    // ...
}

public HttpResponseMessage Post(HttpRequestMessage request, User user)
{
    // ...
}

public void Put(int userId, User user)
{
    // ...
}
```

And this is `WebApiConfig` class:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

When I try to do a PUT on `api/Users/4` I get an error telling me that it only allows GET. This is the response when I do a Put:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Allow: GET
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcVWljMTguSUNcU291cmNlc1xSZXBvc1xWaWEgQ29nbml0YVxNYXR0XHNyY1xNYXR0LlNvY2lhbE5ldHdvcmsuV2ViLkFwaVxhcGlcVXNlcnNcMQ==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 04 Sep 2014 10:04:26 GMT
Content-Length: 68

{"Message":"The requested resource does not support the method http 'PUT'."}
```

Do you know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: _"an error telling me that it only allows GET"_ - show the **actual** error. Or rather, research it.

Comment: Have you mapped PUT verbs to the ExtensionlessUrlHandler in IIS/Web.config (it should be there by default I think, but good to check).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your action is defined to take the user id with a parameter name of `userId` but your routing is set up to use `{id}`. It should read:

```
public void Put(int id, User user)
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Never in a million years do I think that that is the problem.